# Is there any reason to ever prefer variadic parameter to iterable type-hint?

Tags: php

On the syntax level, these two approaches work identicaly:

```php
<?php

function provideGenerator(): \Generator {
    echo "[gInit]";
    yield 0=>1;
    echo "[gMid]";
    yield 1=>2;
    echo "[gEnd]";
}
function provideArray(): array {
    return [1,2];
}
function provideIterator(): Iterator {
    return new ArrayIterator(provideArray());
}

function acceptIterable(iterable $iterable) {
    echo "iterable ". \gettype($iterable). ": ";
    foreach ($iterable as $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
function acceptVariadic(...$variadic) {
    echo "variadic ". \gettype($variadic). ": ";
    foreach ($variadic as $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

acceptIterable(provideGenerator());
acceptIterable(provideArray());
acceptIterable(provideIterator());
acceptIterable([1,2]);

acceptVariadic(...provideGenerator());
acceptVariadic(...provideArray());
acceptVariadic(...provideIterator());
acceptVariadic(1,2);
```

Resulting:

```
iterable object: [gInit]1[gMid]2[gEnd]
iterable array: 12
iterable object: 12
iterable array: 12
[gInit][gMid][gEnd]variadic array: 12
variadic array: 12
variadic array: 12
variadic array: 12
```

**Obviously the iterable approach has a lot of benefits:**

- is not unrolling upon passing of the parameter
- allowing to pass keys
- spread operator unrolls and converts to array, not only the original type is lost, it takes O(n) time.
- spread operator has the quirk of `Error: Cannot unpack Traversable with string keys`
- variadic parameter must be the last parameter, less flexible in refactoring/API extending

**What are the reasons to ever use the variadic parameter?**

- apart from "can be type hinted"?

Comment: Just to be clear, `function acceptSpread(...$spread)` is a variadic function, and `acceptSpread(...provideArray())` is a call to a function using the spread operator. They use the same syntax, which if you read the RFCs ([1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array), [2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking), [3](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics)) was intentional, but they aren't the same thing. So I guess, are you asking about the operator,  variadic functions, or both?

Comment: Ak, OK, thank you for cleaning up my vocabulary.

Comment: I guess besides type-hinting, variadic functions don't require you to wrap your values, you can use them in their native format, which is shown by `acceptVariadic(1,2)`. The documentation talks about by-ref, too, but I don't know how that compares to iterable. But otherwise it was intended to replace `func_get_args()` with `array_slice` which was a very common pattern at a certain point, but I think is much less common these days.

Comment: I'd like to draw your attention to [this page in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and particularly "If your motivation for asking the question is 'I would like to participate in a discussion about ______', then you should not be asking here."

Comment: Wrapping the values is only matter of adding square brackets. That is not a benefit, it is hiding what happens under hood anyways. To me it seems like someone was trying to cure a widely spread bad code design by introducing a syntax feature. Which did not bring any benefits in the long run and seems to have gotten really obsolete. Arrays and \Generator support references, no problem there (but not \Traversable afaik).

Comment: @IMSoP thank you for the hint but that is not the case. I am interested in the reasons I should ever consider using variadic parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Haas is right, you're confusing accepting variadic parameters and passing parameters with a spread operator. That's not just a vocabulary mistake, it's at the heart of your question.

A variadic function is one which can receive any number of parameters. You can call it just like any other function, you don't need to know it's variadic:

```
acceptVariadic(1, 2, 3);
```

A common example would be printf - note that you don't need an array to call it, but the number of parameters is variable and unlimited:

```
printf('%s %s', 'a', 'b');
```

The spread operator is for the *opposite* case: when you have an array or iterable, but the function takes separate arguments:

```
$params = [1,2,3];
someFunc(...$params);
// equivalent to
soneFunc(1,2,3);
```

Here, the function doesn't know that you're using an iterable, it sees the individual parameters.

Using both features at once somewhat defeats the point: if you know you always have an iterable, there's no point spreading it and then collecting it back together in a variadic parameter. So, I'm going to ignore all the discussion in your question of the cost of the spread operator, as irrelevant to real-world uses of variadic functions.

More specifically, variadic functions make most sense when the *caller* knows exactly how many arguments they want to pass, but the *definition* wants to support a variety of use cases. Collecting the parameters into an array is an implementation detail of *how* the definition supports that, not something the caller is interested in.

Taking the printf example, someone writing `printf('%s %s %s', $x, $y, $z);` can simply read it as a normal function call with 4 parameters. There *is* a version which instead expects the parameters as a list - `vprintf('%s %s %s', [$x, $y, $z]);` - but it's rarely used in my experience.

For some functions, there is a common case such as 1 or 2 values, but no distinction between those and further arguments - this is common in PHP's array functions:

```
$foo = array_merge($array1, $array2); // common case
$foo = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3); // variadic case

array_push($array, $value); // common case
array_push($array, $value1, $value2); // variadic case

$foo = array_map($callback, $array); // common case
$foo = array_map($callback, $array1, $array2); // variadic case
```

Passing a list of arrays instead would just be clutter for the common cases, which users would have to remember to add even if they never passed any extra arguments:

```
$foo = array_merge([$array1, $array2]);
array_push($array, [$value]);
$foo = array_map($callback, [$array]);
```

In the end, it's mostly a decision of style, not practical benefit. As you've mentioned, PHP's current implementation does have the advantage of allowing you to type hint the variadic arguments, but mostly it's about allowing direct calls to read more naturally.

Comment: You are not right. What I am demonstrating is just that what I am saying: that variadic parameter is transparently replaceable with iterable type-hint - with many more benefits. To me, it seems like a bad syntactic feature and was a wrong decision to introduce it to PHP. Look, I use the spread operator only to demonstrate the equivalency. Even worse, the spread operator is a helper which eats up O(n) resources. On the other side, the array-wrapping `acceptIterable([1,2]);` is no burden - it is happening in variadic call anyhow. So it seems like false magic and provides zero added value.

Comment: Spread operator is great, I do not have anything against that. And what I mean with transparently replaceable is, that with a bit of different syntax, the source code needs no structural refactoring: the use cases are the same, there is not a case where variadic could not be replaced by iterable type-hint. The `vprintf` is obviously a superior design: is keeps form and content in two separate spaces - it keeps the mental model clean.

Comment: @informatik-handwerk.de I've added some more to the end of my answer. It may not convince you that _you_ should write variadic functions, but maybe it will help you understand why _some people_ want to write them.